# How to solve the com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert data into mySQL and I meet the error below. I've tried the same code but changed the SQL statement to update and it worked. And I've tried to use a SQL statement like below, it didn't worked.

```
        String sql = "insert into movie_preferences values (userID=1001, movieID=1067,preference=5,timestamp=10000000)" ;
```

ERROR:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at com.movie.dao.movieDAO.getMovieMap(movieDAO.java:164)
at com.movie.domain.RecommendMovieList.<init>(RecommendMovieList.java:21)
at com.movie.action.LoadRecommendMovies.execute(LoadRecommendMovies.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)

at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

CODE:

```
public static void insertRating(int userID, int movieID, int preference){
    Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + USER_ID_COLUMN
            + ", " + MOVIE_ID_COLUMN + ", " + RATING + ", " + TIMESTAMP
            + ") values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(userID));
        ps.setInt(2, Integer.valueOf(movieID));
        ps.setInt(3, Integer.valueOf(preference));
        ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(l+""));
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The structure of the table

```
mysql> desc movie_preferences;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userID     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| movieID    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| preference | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| timestamp  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.33 sec)
```

Comment: Nobody noticed that very wrong "ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(l+""));" bit in the code yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to say `insert into <table> values(...)`, you forgot the `values` keyword.

Comment: oops! I forgot it when I type it in the question. It's not the answer but my trans writing mistake:(

Answer (score 1):

best practice would be to list out the columns and then provide the values.  Something like this:

```
insert into movie_preferences (userID, movieID,preference,timestamp )
values (1001, 1067, 5, 10000000)
```

Comment: thank you, but it didn't worked:( I believe there might be something wrong in other parts of the code.

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,value4)

Answer (score 1):

Just reviewing the code - do you have a value for TABLE_NAME?

please try to hardcode the actual table name in that place and see if your error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Write your query the following way, may be you need single quotes for enclosing the values you want to insert if the type of the values is not integer

```
String sql = "insert into movie_preferences Values(1001, 1067, 5, 10000000)" ;
```

Comment: if your problem is solved then my answer should be accepted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 String sql = "insert into movie_preferences(userID,movieID,preference,timestamp) values(1001,1067,5,10000000)" ;
```

please check it

Answer (score 0):

The way you implement your function `insertRating` is not the good approach. What you can do is to simply change your `sql` query as follow :

`"insert into movie_preferences(userID,movieID,preference,timestamp)values(1001,1067,5,10000000)"`.

Also, you should put an Auto ID for the primary key.